Using elaboration system task in a package
I want to validate the existence of a parameter using elaboration system tasks (system verilog standard, section 20.11), see example below, in a package.
I have used this method within modules, which worked fine, but getting a syntax error when used inside a package.
Is there a way to make it work?
`ifdef param
    \\some logic
`else
    $fatal("parameter is not defined")


Packages do not go through the elaboration step like modules where they instantiated with parameter overrides. Your param is a text macro definition, not a parameter definition.  If you want an error message simply  because a text macro is not defined, just try to use it and you get syntax error message.
